# Coproducts and direct products

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory, modules

Is the arbitrary direct sum of modules a submodule of their coproduct?

Ie is $\underset{i \in I}{\coprod} M_i \cong \underset{i \in I}{\bigoplus} M_i$... if not then if each $M_i$ where to be isomorphic whould the isomorphism hold?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The direct sum of modules *is* their coproduct.

In general the underlying set of a coproduct of modules is not the coproduct (i.e. disjoint union) of their underlying sets.

(It doesn't make sense to talk about $\coprod_{i \in I} M_i$ as being a module until you endow it with the structure of a module.)

Comment: So then in the case of modules... $Hom(N,\underset{i \in I}{\bigoplus} M) \cong \underset{i \in I}{\bigoplus} Hom(N,M) \cong Hom(\underset{i \in I}{\prod} N,M) $?

Comment: I don't understand your question... you haven't indexed the modules that you're taking the direct sum / product of.

Comment: Im assuming $M_i \cong M$ for each i, likewise $N_i \cong N$ for each I.  (Moreover, I'm assuming them to be free modules, if that makes a difference)

Comment: Where can I find a proof of this tho.. since the second isomorphism I stated above .... isn't true in general tho... (if I is infinite :/ ) and I'm not certain about how to approach the proof...

Comment: Your claim is incorrect. Instead we have $\mathrm{Hom}(\bigoplus_{i \in I} M_i, N) \cong \prod_{i \in I} \mathrm{Hom} (M_i, N)$ and $\mathrm{Hom}(M, \prod_{i \in I} N_i) \cong \prod_{i \in I} \mathrm{Hom}(M, N_i)$.